# From a newby: Can one mediawiki installaiton have two wikis?

Tags: mediawiki

We are planning to use mediawiki as the basis for our products documentation. Access control will be used to grant customers access to content.

We would also like to use mediawiki for some of our internal documentation, stuff that customers should not access.

Is it possible to configure one installation of mediawiki such that one group of users sees certain wiki content and that another group of users sees other wiki content? If so, please point me to the appropriate documentation as I am not even sure what this would be called (thus I am uncertain where to look).

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean, that you want to restrict the "view" permission for certain pages to a specific group, then the answer is kind of maybe. With the default MediaWiki installation, that is not possible, as MediaWiki is designed to be "open" to all users (as least the view persmission). You can "just" restrict, that a certain group can read or can't read, but this will always mean all pages.

Maybe your problem can be solved by having *really* two wikis, instead of holding two "sections" in *one* wiki. For this you would need:

- One MediaWiki installation on your file system (unzipping the mediawiki tarball release), e.g. /var/www/html/mediawiki/
- Two mysql databases (or you use two database prefixes)
- Two different urls (e.g. example.com/wiki1 and example.com/wiki2 or wiki1.example.com and wiki2.example.com)
- A bit more complex MediaWiki configuration

Now, you first need to create two virtual hosts in your webserver. Both should point to the installation directory of your mediawiki (/var/www/mediawiki/). In the next step you would need to create a configuration which will be different depending on the wiki requested by the user (depending on what url is used). This is a bit tricky and a mostly undocumented way in MediaWiki, but in fact it's working like this:

- You [create a wgConf object](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgConf)
- You fill this wgConf object with valid wikis (usually you use a unique name, e.g. the dbname)
- You let wgConf extract all settings (using the name of the wiki, e.g. the dbname)

This part is more or less documented at the wgConf manual page. The more tricky way is to parse the url correctly and set all the information you need. The Wikimedia foundation uses a script called [MultiVersion](https://github.com/wikimedia/operations-mediawiki-config/tree/master/multiversion). This tool does a bit more as just parsing the url to indentify the wiki, but ok. With MultiVersion you would then set the configuration variable [wgDBname](https://github.com/wikimedia/operations-mediawiki-config/blob/master/wmf-config/CommonSettings.php#L84) which you then use to load the wgConf data. For more information, you should ask specific questions and look into the git repository of the [Wikimedia foundations configuration](https://github.com/wikimedia/operations-mediawiki-config). I [use a similar approach with just 2 wikis](https://github.com/droidwiki/operations-mediawiki-config), and a lot smaller MultiVersion (but it's based on the idea of the WMF), so maybe this will help you understand the way to configure wikis, too.

You want, e.g., also make sure, that the wikis are able to [create inter-wiki links](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Interwiki) to link, e.g., a documentation of your public wiki in your internal wiki and vice versa. And you probably want to make sure, that some database tables are shared by one wiki, so your users just need to register once to access both wikis (and set the internal read permission for users to false, so that you have to give access to users ecplicitly). See $[wgSharedDB](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgSharedDB) and the manual for [shared databases](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Shared_database). The configuration of my two wikis uses this feature to share user tables.

Comment: I need some guidance: Both Tgr and you provided helpful information. Tgr posted first, but your response was more thorough. (And what I took away from both responses is that what I had asked is possible, but non-trivial to implement.) My question is this: What is the StackExchange etiquette regarding marking a response as the answer when both can be so marked?

Comment: Just a reminder: StackOverflow doesn't show the first answer at the top, it shows the last answer, so in fact, I answered "earlier". However, that doesn't really matter for me :P For your question: I'm not sure, if there's an etiquette, I know only http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: I think answers with the same score are ordered randomly. The etiquette is definitely to value more thorough or informative answers over quick ones.

Answer (score 3):

If by one installation you mean one database, it is sort of possible but extremely unwise. See [this section](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Preventing_access#Restrict_viewing_of_certain_specific_pages) of the manual for explanation and [Category:Page specific user rights extensions](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Category:Page_specific_user_rights_extensions) (especially the [Lockdown](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Lockdown) extension) if you decide to try it anyway.

Using the same installation directory (ie. PHP files) but separate databases is fine. The manual page about [wiki farms](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Wiki_family) describes a few ways to do it.

Comment: Thank you. See my question below in the reply to Florian.